# Pass a value between two different vue components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am building an app using vue.js and I have a simple question. Im trying to transfer a value between two componenets which are not related to each other. What I actually do is that I have a chart and when I click on a point, I am assigning the points date to a var and trying to transfer it to the second component and give it to the datepicker. So the main question is that if it is possible to take a value ,which is different depending on the point clicked, and transfer it to the second vue component.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You either store the value in a central store like vuex/pinia or you can use the parent of the two components to provide a state object and store/reference the date from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the value as a prop: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#passing-static-or-dynamic-props

If you need the prop to be reactive: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/data-methods.html#data-properties

And please do not use var, use const (for variables that should not change reference) or let (for variables that may change references).